# Adding multiple variables and outputting to specific div on special event. (jQuery and Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a layout for what I would call, "NHL Line Picker". What it does is allow a user to analyze total point production of a 3-man forward line, by calculating their combined total points for the season, and outputting it to a div on the right side of the screen.

I am unable to figure out a solution to add the three current selected players points together, and output that final total to the div in the right hand side. 
For quick reference, I store a `data-total-pst` attribute within each players `li` tag within the html which I am using in my jQuery.

You can visit a working copy of it at [NHL Line Picker](http://danielzuzevich.com/bostonbruins)

P.S. You'll notice towards the top of the javascript file that I am using append to display the total points onto the screen. I know this is wrong, but I was using it to test if it would at least output something there. I was under the impression I would have to convert each to an integer, but I'm lost after this part.

(Make sure you view the working example on a laptop screen or higher, I haven't done any media queries for it to work on smaller devices, and probably won't since this is just a sample project to practice my javascript.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#left-wingers').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var leftWingTotal = $(this).data('total-pts');
    $('#results').find('#total-display').append(leftWingTotal);
  });

  $('#centers').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var centerTotal = $(this).data('total-pts');
    $('#results').find('#total-display').append(centerTotal);
  });

  $('#right-wingers').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var rightWingTotal = $(this).data('total-pts');
    $('#results').find('#total-display').append(rightWingTotal);
  });

  // Add Center
  $('#centers').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('#selected-players').find('#center-pic').html($(this).data('src'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#center-name').html($(this).data('name'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#center-goals').html($(this).data('goals'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#center-assists').html($(this).data('assists'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#center-skills').html($(this).data('skills'));
  });

  // Add Right Wingers
  $('#right-wingers').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('#selected-players').find('#right-wing-pic').html($(this).data('src'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#right-wing-name').html($(this).data('name'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#right-wing-goals').html($(this).data('goals'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#right-wing-assists').html($(this).data('assists'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#right-wing-skills').html($(this).data('skills'));
  });

  // Add Left Wingers
  $('#left-wingers').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('#selected-players').find('#left-wing-pic').html($(this).data('src'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#left-wing-name').html($(this).data('name'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#left-wing-goals').html($(this).data('goals'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#left-wing-assists').html($(this).data('assists'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#left-wing-skills').html($(this).data('skills'));
  });

  //Clear All Button
  $('#results').on('click', '#clear-all', function() {
    $('#selected-players').find('#left-wing-skills,#left-wing-assists,#left-wing-goals,#left-wing-name,#left-wing-pic').text("");
    $('#selected-players').find('#right-wing-skills,#right-wing-assists,#right-wing-goals,#right-wing-name,#right-wing-pic').text("");
    $('#selected-players').find('#center-skills,#center-assists,#center-goals,#center-name,#center-pic').text("");
    $('#results').find('#total-display').empty();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bruins Line Picker</title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:400,500,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <!-- App Title -->
  <div id="title" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <img src="img/bruins-logo.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <h1>Forward Lines</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
        <img src="img/nhl-logo.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Column Setup -->
  <div id="setup" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="#roster" class="col-md-2">
        <h2>Positions</h2>
        <ul id="centers">
          <h3>Centers</h3>
          <li id="bergeron" data-src="<img src='img/patrice.png'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Perfect player. Can play with anyone.</p>" data-name="<h4>Patrice Bergeron</h4>" data-goals="28" data-assists="33" data-total-pts="61">Bergeron, Patrice</li>
          <li id="krejci" data-src="<img src='img/krejci.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Elite caliber player when he feels like it.</p>" data-name="<h4>David Krejci</h4>" data-goals="19" data-assists="45" data-total-pts="64">Krejci, David</li>
          <li id="ferraro" data-src="<img src='img/ferraro.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Not to sure what he brings to the table.</p>" data-name="<h4>Landon Ferraro</h4>" data-goals="10" data-assists="10" data-total-pts="20">Ferraro, Landon</li>
          <li id="spooner" data-src="<img src='img/spooner.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Elite speed. Playmaker abilities.</p>" data-name="<h4>Ryan Spooner</h4>" data-goals="15" data-assists="40" data-total-pts="55">Spooner, Ryan</li>
          <li id="kelly" data-src="<img src='img/kelly.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>A reliable two-way player.</p>" data-name="<h4>Chris Kelly</h4>" data-goals="10" data-assists="20" data-total-pts="30">Kelly, Chris</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="right-wingers">
          <h3>Right Wingers</h3>
          <li id="beleskey" data-src="<img src='img/beleskey.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Plays physical. Can score out front.</p>" data-name="<h4>Matt Beleskey</h4>" data-goals="18" data-assists="20" data-total-pts="38">Matt Beleskey</li>
          <li id="connolly" data-src="<img src='img/connolly.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Useless.</p>" data-name="<h4>Brett Connolly</h4>" data-goals="12" data-assists="18" data-total-pts="30">Brett Connolly</li>
          <li id="eriksson" data-src="<img src='img/loui.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Veteran, goal scorer, and play-maker.</p>" data-name="<h4>Loui Eriksson</h4>" data-goals="25" data-assists="25" data-total-pts="50">Loui Eriksson</li>
          <li id="hayes" data-src="<img src='img/hayes.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Why???</p>" data-name="<h4>Jimmy Hayes</h4>" data-goals="15" data-assists="15" data-total-pts="30">Jimmy Hayes</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="left-wingers">
          <h3>Left Wingers</h3>
          <li id="pastrnak" data-src="<img src='img/pasta.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Pure goal scorer. High speed and skill.</p>" data-name="<h4>David Pastrnak</h4>" data-goals="20" data-assists="20" data-total-pts="40">David Pastrnak</li>
          <li id="marchand" data-src="<img src='img/marchand.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Great wrist shot and overall speed.</p>" data-name="<h4>Brad Marchand</h4>" data-goals="35" data-assists="20" data-total-pts="55">Brad Marchand</li>
          <li id="randall" data-src="<img src='img/randell.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>No comment.</p>" data-name="<h4>Tyler Randell</h4>" data-goals="10" data-assists="15" data-total-pts="25">Tyler Randell</li>
          <li id="stempniak" data-src="<img src='img/stemp.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Veteran, with play-maker abilities</p>" data-name="<h4>Lee Stempniak</h4>" data-goals="15" data-assists="15" data-total-pts="30">Lee Stempniak</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- End Roster -->

      <div id="selected-players" class="col-md-8 text-center">
        <!-- Nested Row -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Left Wing</h2>
            <div id="left-wing-pic" class="photo">

            </div>
            <div id="left-wing-name">

            </div>
            <div id="left-wing-goals">

            </div>
            <div id="left-wing-assists">

            </div>
            <div id="left-wing-skills">

            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Centerman</h2>
            <div id="center-pic" class="photo">

            </div>
            <div id="center-name">

            </div>
            <div id="center-goals">

            </div>
            <div id="center-assists">

            </div>
            <div id="center-skills">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Right Wing</h2>
            <div id="right-wing-pic" class="photo">

            </div>
            <div id="right-wing-name">

            </div>
            <div id="right-wing-goals">

            </div>
            <div id="right-wing-assists">

            </div>
            <div id="right-wing-skills">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Nested Row -->
      </div>
      <div id="results" class="col-md-2">
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <div id="total-display">
        </div>
        <button id="clear-all">Clear</button>
        <button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the function for each position into one this way:

> Using an array to store the value for each position and then + all values.

```
var total=['0','0','0'];

$('#roster ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var i = $(this).parent('ul').index('ul');
  total[i] = $(this).data('total-pts');

  var output = 0;
  $.each(total,function(){output+=parseFloat(this) || 0;});

  $('#total-display').html(output);
});
```

---

**Example Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var total=['0','0','0'];
  
  $('#roster ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var i = $(this).parent('ul').index('ul');
    total[i] = $(this).data('total-pts');
    
    var output = 0;
    $.each(total,function(){output+=parseFloat(this) || 0;});
    
    $('#total-display').html(output);
  });



  // Add Center
  $('#centers').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('#selected-players').find('#center-pic').html($(this).data('src'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#center-name').html($(this).data('name'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#center-goals').html($(this).data('goals'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#center-assists').html($(this).data('assists'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#center-skills').html($(this).data('skills'));
  });

  // Add Right Wingers
  $('#right-wingers').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('#selected-players').find('#right-wing-pic').html($(this).data('src'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#right-wing-name').html($(this).data('name'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#right-wing-goals').html($(this).data('goals'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#right-wing-assists').html($(this).data('assists'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#right-wing-skills').html($(this).data('skills'));
  });

  // Add Left Wingers
  $('#left-wingers').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('#selected-players').find('#left-wing-pic').html($(this).data('src'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#left-wing-name').html($(this).data('name'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#left-wing-goals').html($(this).data('goals'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#left-wing-assists').html($(this).data('assists'));
    $('#selected-players').find('#left-wing-skills').html($(this).data('skills'));
  });

  //Clear All Button
  $('#results').on('click', '#clear-all', function() {
    $('#selected-players').find('#left-wing-skills,#left-wing-assists,#left-wing-goals,#left-wing-name,#left-wing-pic').text("");
    $('#selected-players').find('#right-wing-skills,#right-wing-assists,#right-wing-goals,#right-wing-name,#right-wing-pic').text("");
    $('#selected-players').find('#center-skills,#center-assists,#center-goals,#center-name,#center-pic').text("");
    $('#results').find('#total-display').empty();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="roster" class="col-md-2">
  <h2>Positions</h2>
  <h3>Centers</h3>
  <ul id="centers">
    <li id="spooner" data-src="<img src='img/spooner.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Elite speed. Playmaker abilities.</p>" data-name="<h4>Ryan Spooner</h4>" data-goals="15" data-assists="40" data-total-pts="55">Spooner, Ryan</li>
    <li id="kelly" data-src="<img src='img/kelly.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>A reliable two-way player.</p>" data-name="<h4>Chris Kelly</h4>" data-goals="10" data-assists="20" data-total-pts="30">Kelly, Chris</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Right Wingers</h3>
  <ul id="right-wingers">
    <li id="beleskey" data-src="<img src='img/beleskey.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Plays physical. Can score out front.</p>" data-name="<h4>Matt Beleskey</h4>" data-goals="18" data-assists="20" data-total-pts="38">Matt Beleskey</li>
    <li id="connolly" data-src="<img src='img/connolly.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Useless.</p>" data-name="<h4>Brett Connolly</h4>" data-goals="12" data-assists="18" data-total-pts="30">Brett Connolly</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Left Wingers</h3>

  <ul id="left-wingers">
    <li id="pastrnak" data-src="<img src='img/pasta.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Pure goal scorer. High speed and skill.</p>" data-name="<h4>David Pastrnak</h4>" data-goals="20" data-assists="20" data-total-pts="40">David Pastrnak</li>
    <li id="marchand" data-src="<img src='img/marchand.jpg'>" data-skills="<p id='skills'>Great wrist shot and overall speed.</p>" data-name="<h4>Brad Marchand</h4>" data-goals="35" data-assists="20" data-total-pts="55">Brad Marchand</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- End Roster -->

<div id="selected-players" class="col-md-8 text-center">
  <!-- Nested Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Left Wing</h2>
      <div id="left-wing-pic" class="photo">

      </div>
      <div id="left-wing-name">

      </div>
      <div id="left-wing-goals">

      </div>
      <div id="left-wing-assists">

      </div>
      <div id="left-wing-skills">

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Centerman</h2>
      <div id="center-pic" class="photo">

      </div>
      <div id="center-name">

      </div>
      <div id="center-goals">

      </div>
      <div id="center-assists">

      </div>
      <div id="center-skills">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Right Wing</h2>
      <div id="right-wing-pic" class="photo">

      </div>
      <div id="right-wing-name">

      </div>
      <div id="right-wing-goals">

      </div>
      <div id="right-wing-assists">

      </div>
      <div id="right-wing-skills">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Nested Row -->
</div>
<div id="results" class="col-md-2">
  <h2>Results</h2>
  <div id="total-display">
  </div>
  <button id="clear-all">Clear</button>
  <button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you are saying I can get rid of those 3 blocks and just use this? I deleted the 3 functions and dumped this in instead and nothing shows up in the right div.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich I've change also in the html `<div id="#roster" class="col-md-2">` to this `<div id="roster" class="col-md-2">` if you change that will work ... or just remove `#roster` from the jquery function check the snippet

Comment: You're a beast! It works! Do I just upvote this, or is there a way to give you any more points for answering? Sorry, Stack Overflow noob here.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer. Now I am going to study exactly wtf it is that you did there. Thank you very much sir. There are no additional issues, it is doing exactly what I asked you for it to do. No further help is needed. May the Javascript Gods bless you with bountiful amounts of karma.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich glad to help U if you have any question about the code let me know .. you can also optimize  other functions . Have a nice day

Comment: Oh I def will ask if I have a question, I haven't even looked into the initial solution you sent yet because it looks like alien gibberish, but prob tomorrow I'll sit down and give it a nice comb through and search some things on the ol' google.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the sum like below in your function -

```
 $('#left-wingers').on('click', 'li', function() {
     var leftWingTotal = $(this).data('total-pts');
     var curTextStr = ($('#total-display').text() !== '')? $('#total-display').text(): 0;
     var newTextStr = parseInt(currentStr, 10) + parseInt(leftWingTotal,10);
     $('#total-display').text(newTextStr);
 });
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hey Hector. Replacing the function to this breaks the program and stops display the images, and does not output any data to the right div. My goal is to add the three players total-pts together in a mathematical function sort of way. This looks like it just keeps outputting text values and doesnt convert anything to integers.

Comment: Not sure I was clear enough in the initial description. I initially was trying to  convert each variable from a text value to an integer, then somehow create a new master variable that computes the addition of those three variables. The plan would be to then take that master variable, and display it in the right div, showing the user the integer value of how many total points that line would score in a season combined.

Comment: In my current edit, I am adding the total points with the existing value of total-display section.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for a solution that did not output any of the individual points to the right div, but only displayed the output of the master variable I was talking about, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to track the active player's points differently for it to add properly. The code can obviously be optimized in a million different ways, but in the essence of time, I just used data attributes attached to `$('#selected-players')`. Here I initialize them to 0 to prevent any `NaN` errors:

```
$('#selected-players').data('left-pts', 0)
$('#selected-players').data('center-pts', 0)
$('#selected-players').data('right-pts', 0)
```

I also added that this snip to your "Clear All" function.

Here I added a snippet to your "Right Wingers" click event which populates the data attribute, totals up all 3 data-attributes (using parseInt to cast values as integer), then injects the total into `#total-display`:

```
$('#selected-players').data('right-pts', $(this).data('total-pts'));

total = parseInt( $('#selected-players').data('left-pts') + parseInt( $('#selected-players').data('center-pts') ) + parseInt( $('#selected-players').data('right-pts') )

$('#results').find('#total-display').html(total);
```

I added similar snips to  "Center Wingers" and  "Left Wingers".

Now when you click a player, it updates the respective data-attribute w/ the player's total pts, adds up the left/center/right data-attributes, and updates the total with a (hopefully) accurate value.

You can see a working demo here: http://codepen.io/JeffreyPia/pen/oLbwxQ